# Assert Statement for Preselected Dropdown Value Innertext Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have an html sample here:

```
  <select id="Something" style="color:#404040;background-color:White;font-family:Verdana;font-size:XX-Small;width:125px;z-index: 134" name="Something">
  <option value="0">Please Choose Status</option>
  <option value="1">Status1</option>
  <option value="2">Status2</option>
```

The above is in reference to a dropdown webelement. Based on workflow selected, the system will trigger either value 1 or 2 depending on the condition. How do I write an Assert statement to check the actual status vs the expected? I have tried the following:

```
 Assert.True(ddlFoo.Text.Equals("Status2"));
Assert.AreEqual("Status2", ddlFoo.Selected);
            Assert.AreEqual("Status2",ddlFoo.Text);
```

however, all three of these seem to be comparing the innertext against the entire dropdown for example

```
Instead of `"status2 compared to status1"`
```

I get :  `"status2" compared to "Please Choose Status\r\nStatus1r\nStatus2"`

Can someone provide me with the C# syntax to do an Assert Statement for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SelectElement` class and the [`.SelectedOption` property](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement_SelectedOption.htm):

```
SelectElement selectElm = new SelectElement(ddlFoo);
Assert.AreEqual("Status2", selectElm.SelectedOption.Text);
```